# How to update ListView when Cursor is changed?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I do something like below:

```
public class WhitelistActivity extends ListActivity {
    private DbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private Cursor recordsCursor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.whitelist);

        dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();
        recordsCursor = dbHelper.fetchWhitelistRecords();
        startManagingCursor(recordsCursor);
        String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_W_SENDER};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.whitelist_row, recordsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ...

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                dbHelper.deleteWhitelistRecord(info.id);
                adapter.changeCursor(recordsCursor);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }   
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

However, when context menu is called and item is deleted, it is not reflected on the list view. What am I missing?

Comment: you need to either requery or recreate your cursor. In you code, you simply reuse it without it being requeried to reflect the changes.

Comment: @njzk2, how exactly should I do it? I've expected that `changeCursor` or `swapCursor` does it.

Comment: either recreate (`recordsCursor = dbHelper.fetchWhitelistRecords();`) the cursor, or requery it (`recordsCursor.requery()`) (but this is deprecated as of api11. I still mention it as you use startManagingCursor, which is also deprecated)

Comment: Thanks, @njzk2. Actually I've alread recreate it like you've described - `recordsCursor = dbHelper.fetchWhitelistRecords();`. Please post it as the answer, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change your cursor, you need to update its content. The simplest and recommended way is to create a new cursor (if possible in a Loaded).

```
recordsCursor = dbHelper.fetchWhitelistRecords();
adapter.changeCursor(recordsCursor);
```

It is not necessary to notifyDataSetChanged.

Answer (score 2):

The Cursor isn't updated until you requery the database. startManagingCursor doesn't do this automatically. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() "updates" the ListView, but since the Cursor hasn't changed, nothing happens.

What you should *really* consider doing is encapsulating your database in a ContentProvider and then using CursorLoader to manage the Cursor and requeries. If you do this, life becomes much simpler. See [Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html) to learn how to set up CursorLoader. Encapsulating a database in a ContentProvider is also straightforward, see the API guide
[Creating a Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html).